# accessing uart2 on Freescale kl25z running nuttx

Tags: arm, uart, cortex-m

I cannot find any documentation on how to get this up and running. Def a newb when it comes to this kind of stuff... if anyone can provide any suggestions or support I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

NuttX uses UART1 be default.  To switch to UART1,

make distclean

cd tools

./cofigure.sh freedom-kl25z/nsh

cd ..

make menuconfig

Under System Type -> Peripherals, disable UART1 and enable UART2

Under Device Drivers -> Serial, Select the UART1 console and UART1 baud as you like